# Revtex 4.1 bibliography style in other classes

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I'd like to know if someone ported the bibliography styles used in revtex 4.1 (like apsrev4-1.bst) so they can be used in other classes, like book.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just did a test using the `book` class with `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}` and everything worked OK. Have you had any problems?

Comment: I get some errors when compiling after running bibtex, like this:


`(./main.bbl (./main.brf))
Runaway argument?
\BibitemOpen \bibfield {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {R.\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \BR@@lbibitem.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.166 \bibliography{tex/references}
`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks if the revtex bst's are highly customized for for the class file. I have found that the following gives more or less the same output with a standard class

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\usepackage{doi}%<----------
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

It also needs an additional bibtex file with a custom setup especially if you want the full article names included (the `longbibliography` option in `revtex4-1`). Create the following file, say `revtex-custom.bib` with contents

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="48",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}
```

Define your bib then as follows:

```
\nocite{apsrev41Control}
\bibliography{my-bib,revtex-custom}
```

Comment: Thanks, In order to make it work the way you described, I had to comment out hyperref and load nohyperref, but the whole reason I wanted apsrev are the nice liks pointing to the online versions of the paper. Also, removing hyperref also removed all the links and bookmarks in the file, which is undesired. Apparently, all the customization in the class file is responsible for making the links work. With hyperref enabled, I get the same arror as in my comment above. If anyone knows of a bibligraphy style that makes the journal name and volume a link to its DOI, please let me know.

Comment: @Elton Carvalho: I have added the [doi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/doi) package and activated hyperref. This seems to do what you are asking

Comment: Thanks, man. Now it worked.

I found out that the problem was in my .bib file. ISI Web of Knowledge generates dome weird bibliography entries with double braces for years and volumes and apsrev.bst doesn't swallow that very well.

Comment: I appreciate the demonstration of `@control` in your answer but there are several subtle points that caused me problems. 1) You need to "cite" "apsrev41Control" somehow to make sure that the `@CONTROL` block gets processed, and 2) `title="-1"` will fail to disable the titles (for reasons I do not understand yet, `title=-1` will work...).  If you know how to fix these simply, could you ammend your answer?  (Perhaps I should ask another question, but your answer is so close...).  Thanks.

Comment: Just in case somebody can't get the full-title trick to work, putting the @CONTROL lines in the same file as all the other citations solved the problem for me.

Comment: Amazing solution! Is there an official documentation with the internal commands? I want it to automatically transfer capital letters from the title, since I am citing german papers where that is important.

Comment: Is the procedure the same for Revtex 4.2?

Comment: Is it possible to change the output of the article title from quotation marks to italics?

Comment: @aRockStr: The styles are normaly embedded in the .bst files. Not so easy to change

Answer (score 5):

I haven't been able to make the `@CONTROL` sequences work as above, but I found a way to tweak `apsrev4-1.bst` to output what you want.  First, copy `apsrev4-1.bst` to a new file named, for example, `apsrev4-1_custom.bst`, and put it in the same directory as your `tex` file.  In it, find the function `control.init`, and modify any options you'd like -- `#0` is false, `#1` is true.  To get the titles to display, change the `#0` above `control.title` to `#1`.  Use this newly modified by running `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1custom}`.