# modification of Revtex 4.1 bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I'm using the `book` class along with `apsrev4-1` bibliographystyle. Everything is fine except from the fact that I'd like titles of the papers that I cite to be visible (not a standard thing in `apsrev4-1` bibliographystyle). Turns out this problem is addressed over here:
[Revtex 4.1 bibliography style in other classes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15677/revtex-4-1-bibliography-style-in-other-classes). Thing is however, that the last suggested solution, i.e., the one including a slight modification of the `apsrev4-1.bst` file, proves to cause the `babel` package errors of the form:

> Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language English yet. ! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option Swedish yet.

which is totally ridiculous and absent when using the unmodified `apsrev4-1.bst` file. When ignoring them the final `.pdf` is produced and everything seems to be fine (the titles of the papers do appear in the bibliography, with some minor issues such as all words in a title but the first one are in lower case) but they are really irritating. I had tried the solution with separate file and `@Control` sequence in there but this one doesn't work at all.

All ideas appreciated,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: That kind of error sounds like you loaded babel before the modification, and now you don't. Try to delete the `.aux` file and see if it helps?

Comment: A comment after a long time: deleting the `aux` did not help then.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to show a MWE of your problem. Using a `@CONTROL` field works fine for me:

```
\begin{filecontents}{apsrevcontrol.bib}
  @CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="00",editor="1",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{apsrev41control}
  As we see in \cite{bs-1629,howells-66-pop,fletcher-hopkins,hoel-71-portion}...
\bibliography{apsrevcontrol,test}
\end{document}
```