# Physical Review X ( Phys Rev X PRX ) bibliography style

Tags: revtex, arxiv

Could an expert please tweak the `ReVTeX 4.1` `BibTeX` style file for the following bibliography format?

[image: Example from [a PRX article](http://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.5.021034).]

There already exists a `RevTeX` style file called [`apsrev`](http://psec.uchicago.edu/library/data/ANL_APS_Data/APSpapers/revtex4-1/bibtex/bst/revtex/apsrev4-1.bst) and, according to the [manual](http://journals.aps.org/files/revtex/summary4-1.pdf), I can call the `longbibliography` option and have it spit out the title. However, that output spells out the author first names and I would like only the first initial. If I don't call `longbibliography`, I get abbreviated first names but no titles.

I've tried the [related solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83130/modification-of-revtex-4-1-bibliography-style?lq=1) but it didn't work for me. Another solution is [here](http://cassandrahunt.com/topics.php?id=LaTeX), but the link to the actual style file is dead. Also note that a previous [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236530/authors-initials-in-longbibliography-for-revtex4-1-aps-style?rq=1) works for `apsrev`, but I could not easily port it to `apsrev4-1`.

Comment: Given the related post was closed, I don't think this is too narrow because RevTeX is the (unfortunately) default option that properly formats physics papers for arXiv and Physical Review journals.

Comment: Please post a minimal example we can compile to work with which shows the solution you tried, and explain in what way that example doesn't work for you. I assume you mean you tried using the control file but I'm not sure, and certainly don't know what happened.

Comment: Sorry for being non-detailed -- I use LyX and it complicates things. Solution below is different from the previous ones, and I'll leave it up to the community to determine whether it should stay or be merged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some searching, I found a fix. Search for `{article}` (including curly brackets) in the `apsrev4-1.bst` file. Then insert the **very intuitive** lines of code as follows:

```
...
author format.key output
new.block.comma
%%% lines of code
format.title
    "title" 'bibfield :=
    emphasize
output
new.block.comma
%%% lines of code
article.title.produce
...
```

Finally, to remove the quotes around the title, search for `bbl.enquote "{" * swap$ * "}" *` and comment it out.

Comment: Remember not to change a file directly, make a copy, rename it and use the renamed and changed file.

Comment: Brilliant! This will help me.

Comment: You could add the include command for the file in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and unfortunately only found the answer given by Victor V Albert after I had already changed the bst file myself.

I did it slightly differently, maybe the following will be useful for someone some day.
This also works if your documentclass is not revtex!

- To have the title displayed, change the `#-1` in line 230 to `#1`.
- To remove the quotes around the title and, at the same time, make it *emph*asized, replace `"\enquote "` in line 1884 with `"\emph "`.
- If you want the title to retain capitalization, comment out line 1901
  (i.e. `duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ { "t" change.case$ } if$`)