# BibTeX: How to show article titles within `apsrev4-1`?

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I'm writing an article using `revtex4-1` format, and in order to generate the bibliography I use the BibTeX style `apsrev4-1`.

Recently, the journal change the bibliography format and are now admitting the article titles in the bibliography.

Is it possible to hack the style to show the titles? Thank you.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,showpacs,showkeys,prd,superscriptaddress,byrevtex]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[%
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\let\cat@comma@active\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{I'm here you're there}

\author{Oscar \surname{Castillo-Felisola}}

\section{\label{phenom}Phenomenological implications}

\cite{Cartan-Einstein,Cartan1922,*Cartan1923,*Cartan1924,*Cartan1925}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

BibTeX entries

```
@Article{Cartan1922,
  author =   {Cartan, Elie},
  title =    {Sur une g\'en\'eralisation de la notion de courbure de Riemann et les espaces \`a torsion},
  journal =      {C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris},
  year =     {1922},
  volume =   {174},
  pages =    {593},
  url       =    {http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3127j.image.langFR},
}

@article{Cartan1923,
  title={Sur les vari{\'e}t{\'e}s {\`a} connexion affine et la th{\'e}orie de la relativit{\'e} g{\'e}n{\'e}ralis{\'e}e (premi{\`e}re partie)},
  author={Cartan, Elie},
  journal={Ann. Ec. Norm. Super.},
  volume={40},
  pages={325},
  year={1923},
  organization={Soci{\'e}t{\'e} math{\'e}matique de France},
  url = "http://archive.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1923_3_40__325_0.pdf",
}

@article{Cartan1924,
  added-at = {2012-03-20T16:46:21.000+0100},
  author = {Cartan, Elie},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/28d419192587558cbe5fb0ef3010fa947/marco.giovanell},
  interhash = {44a9d347ae2ea364f07c0e4e9cdcbfab},
  intrahash = {8d419192587558cbe5fb0ef3010fa947},
  journal = {Ann. Ec. Norm. Super.},
  keywords = {jabref:noKeywordAssigned},
  owner = {marco},
  pages = {1},
  timestamp = {2012-03-20T16:46:21.000+0100},
  title = {Sur les vari\'et\'es \`a connexion affine, et la th\'eorie de la relativit\'e
    g\'en\'eralis\'ee (premi\`ere partie) (Suite)},
  volume = {41},
  year = {1924},
  url = {http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=ASENS_1924_3_41__1_0},
}

@article{Cartan1925,
  added-at = {2012-03-20T16:46:21.000+0100},
  author = {Cartan, Elie},
  biburl = {http://www.bibsonomy.org/bibtex/2a42d27017aaeac461f63112c6604b814/marco.giovanell},
  interhash = {7b4e0980e917b55bf750d1c1fdee61c3},
  intrahash = {a42d27017aaeac461f63112c6604b814},
  journal = {Ann. Ec. Norm. Super.},
  keywords = {jabref:noKeywordAssigned},
  owner = {Marco},
  pages = {17},
  timestamp = {2012-03-20T16:46:21.000+0100},
  title = {Sur les vari\'et\'es \`a connexion affine et la th\'eorie de la relativit\'e
    g\'en\'eralis\'ee, Part II,},
  volume = {42},
  year = {1925},
  url = {http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=ASENS_1925_3_42__17_0},
}

@Book{Cartan-Einstein,
  editor =   {Debever, Robert},
  title =    {Elie Cartan - Albert Einstein Letters on Absolute Parallelism 1929-1932},
  publisher =    {Princeton University Press},
  year =     {1979},
}
```

Comment: Does the journal provide, or suggest, a bibliography style?

Comment: revtex4-2 uses titles by default

Comment: @Andrew Thank you... yes, but it was not yet released at the time! XD

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By suggestion of @Mico, I looked at the webpage of APS and found the following

> **How can I make the titles of cited journal articles appear in the
>   bibliography?**
>
> REVTeX 4.1 calls in a default BibTeX Style (.bst) file for each
>   supported journal. The .bst files support displaying the titles of
>   cited journal articles in the bibliography. To display the titles,
>   simply use the "longbibliography" class option. Consult the REVTeX 4.1
>   documentation for more information.

Thus the solution to my problem would be the following:

- Add the journal global option: in my case `aps,prd`
- Add the `longbibliography` global option
- Remove the `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}` line.

Thus, the minimal code would be (after removing some unnecessary options)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,prd,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[%
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\let\cat@comma@active\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{I'm here you're there}

\author{Oscar \surname{Castillo-Felisola}}

\section{\label{phenom}Phenomenological implications}

\cite{Cartan-Einstein,Cartan1922,*Cartan1923,*Cartan1924,*Cartan1925}

\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [revtex-faq](https://journals.aps.org/revtex/revtex-faq#Bibtex) [https://journals.aps.org/revtex/revtex-faq#Bibtex](https://journals.aps.org/revtex/revtex-faq#Bibtex)

Comment: This writes out the first names of the authors as well. Is there any way to display the titles without changing anything else?

Comment: This solution works for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252735/584