# Making BibTeX print a newline in the .bbl file appropriately

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, revtex, bst

BibTeX automatically restricts the generated .bbl file to have at most 80 characters in each line. This can have unintended consequences. For instance, I am using the `apsrev4-1` bibliography style for APS journals, and this style automatically converts DOI (identifiers for scientific papers) from the .bib file into URLs by turning them into the following:
`\href {\doibase xxxx.xxxxx}` where `\doibase` is simply a command that inserts `http://dx.doi.org/` and `xxxx.xxxxx` is the DOI of the given paper. This space does not cause problems in most cases, and the URL gets formatted as `http://dx.doi.org/xxxx.xxxxx` in the bibliography. However, it can happen that BibTeX decides to break the line between `\doibase` and the DOI, in which case a space is added and the URL is formatted as `http://dx.doi.org/ xxxx.xxxxx` which is incorrect and causes problems in some PDF viewers.

I would like to fix this by forcing BibTeX to break the line before each `\href`. I have been trying to modify the .bst file for this but I have been unsuccessful, the `newline$`s do not appear in the appropriate place. How can I force linebreaks before all bibliography links?

### MWE

In order to reproduce this behavior, I will use the bibliography style `apsrev4-1.bst` provided by the package RevTeX, but it also needs to be modified to display article titles, as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352700/145132). The file is very long, so I have copied it here for convenience: [paste.ee/p/tj5zj](https://paste.ee/p/tj5zj).

If you save this file as `apsrev-mod.bst`, the minimal working example is then as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{entry,
  title = {Long title so that it just happens that the line gets broken appropriately},
  author = {Author, A and Author, B},
  year = {2021},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  doi = {xxxx.xxxxx},
  journal = {Journal}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  \cite{entry}

  \bibliographystyle{apsrev-mod}
  \bibliography{bibliography}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about copying the contents of the bbl file, editing it suitably, and putting it inside `\begin{thebibliography}{5}` and `\end{thebibliography}` in your main tex file ?  (be sure to remove lines `\bibliographystyle{apsrev-mod}`, `\bibliography{bibliography}`, and `\begin{filecontents}.....\end{filecontents}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround for your problem that does not involve forcing a line break. Instead of using `\doibase` we simply write out the (new) DOI base URL in the `.bst` file without a space. BibTeX will then not break the line at the space and everything is fine.

The problem with forcing a `newline$` is that the style writes out the entire bibliography entry at once with relatively few `write$` or `newline$` instructions. So if we want to force a new line, we need to get in at exactly the right time. What's more, we can't have a line break before `\href`, because the style hard-codes the previous space with `\`  and the line break would then produce and additional (unwanted) space.

So I would just change the `.bst` file as follows

```
--- apsrev-mod.bst  2021-03-19 08:38:36.360594000 +0100
+++ apsrev-moddoi.bst   2021-03-19 08:38:27.266269000 +0100
@@ -1795,7 +1795,7 @@
 
 FUNCTION {doi.base.command}
 {
-  "\doibase "
+  "https://doi.org/"
 }
 
 FUNCTION {noop.command}
```

The new file is available at https://gist.github.com/moewew/797b5747b6c75bd69dec33f0ecfe8179 and produces the following `.bbl` entry for the MWE

```
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {Author}\ and\ \citenamefont {Author}(2021)}]{entry}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {A.}~\bibnamefont
  {Author}}\ and\ \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {B.}~\bibnamefont
  {Author}},\ }\bibfield  {title} {\emph {\bibinfo {title} {Long title so that
  it just happens that the line gets broken appropriately},}\ }\href
  {https://doi.org/xxxx.xxxxx} {\bibfield  {journal} {\bibinfo  {journal}
  {Journal}\ } (\bibinfo {year} {2021}),\ xxxx.xxxxx}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and makes me mildly angry that I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!