# How do I increase the size of the hyperlink on a superscript numerical citation with natbib?

Tags: hyperref, natbib, revtex, cite-package

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\begin{document}

bla~\cite{bla}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{bla} blabla
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The problem is: when I compile with `pdflatex`, the citation number is a nice clickable link. When I compile with plain latex (tex->dvi(->ps)->pdf, regardless of the PS step or not), the clickable region of the superscripted link is reduced to what seems like a single-pixel line. Footnotes, though, are created fine and the link actually covers the whole symbol.
Is there any way to have this work with the natbib package? Or force the size of a citation label somehow?

An alternative solution I would accept is to be able to force numeric labels without the natbib package, while using the revtex bst files as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15691/174). I can use the `cite` package with the `super` option, but then I have no numeric labels, and huge monstrosities instead.

Comment: When compiling via "plain LaTeX", dvips, and ps2pdf, have you tried loading the `hyperref` package with the option `dvips`?

Comment: @Mico I have now, and it does not solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: You can try `hypdvips`

Comment: @Marco Adding `\usepackage{hypdvips}` after `\usepackage{hyperref}` gives me this an undefined command error for `\ifBR@enable`, even after deleting all temporary files. Was worth a shot though!