# APS reference style without revtex

Tags: bibliographies, revtex, bibliographystyle

I am wondering if there is a way to use the APS reference style in a latex article that does not use the revtex article class? Here is a compilable example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%bibliography
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
    Hello \cite{example}. Hello again \cite{example2}.

    %\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliographystyle{apsrmp4-1}
    \bibliography{mybib}
    
\end{document}
```

with the bibliography `mybib.bib`

```
@article{example,
   author = {Keinstein, A.},
   title  = {Not very general theory of relativity},
   journal= {Astrostuff},
   year   = {1000},
   volume = {1},
   number = {2},
   pages  = {3-4},
  }
 
@article{example2,
    title = {Cool paper},
    author = {X, XX and Y, YY},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. A},
    volume = {1},
    issue = {1},
    pages = {000000},
    numpages = {1},
    year = {2000},
    month = {Jan},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    doi = {00.0000/PhysRevA.00.000000},
}
```

compiles to

[image]

Interestingly only one of the papers is not printed correctly. With the `unsrt` style, on the other hand, this gives a correct output for both papers.

Is there a way for natbib or bibtex to interpret the style file as revtex would? I use the same bibfile as I use in my revtex articles and there I have no problems.

Comment: With `apsrmp4-2` or `apsrev4-2` I see no `\bibinfo` in the output (this command is provided in the `.bbl` file).  Can you please make a compilable example that prints the `\bibinfo`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the question completely. Also after the edit some new "related questions" were suggested by Stackexchange, so I have actually found the solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15677/revtex-4-1-bibliography-style-in-other-classes?rq=1 . I will mark as a duplicate. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah, cool! Glad you found the solution :-)